# Network works very slow

Tags: networking, connection, transfer

My network works very slow on Ubuntu.

```
gkucmierz@gkucmierz-MS-7D70:~$ uname -r
6.2.0-34-generic
gkucmierz@gkucmierz-MS-7D70:~$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
gkucmierz@gkucmierz-MS-7D70:~$ speedtest
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Jerzy Krempa Telpol PPMUE (193.106.84.14)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by UPC Polska (Katowice) [9.54 km]: 15.593 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 9.20 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 10.12 Mbit/s
```

Download is less than 10Mbit/s but other devices on same network work much faster:

```
gkucmierz@MacBook-Pro-Macbook ~ % speedtest
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
/usr/local/bin/speedtest:960: DeprecationWarning: datetime.datetime.utcnow() is deprecated and scheduled for removal in a future version. Use timezone-aware objects to represent datetimes in UTC: datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC).
  self.timestamp = '%sZ' % datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
Testing from Jerzy Krempa Telpol PPMUE (193.106.84.14)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by SOFTPRO2 (Sosnowiec) [1.22 km]: 20.428 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 178.26 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 48.34 Mbit/s
```

Comment: I think I found a problem. Probably I have wrong type of network cable or my rj45 socket is not correctly assembled.

Comment: Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.